# How can I add validation to adding email to my db? Upsert?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to undertstand the best way to do this.

I am getting the name and email and I want to add it to my collection.

However, if the email already exists, then i don't want to insert the name and email.  Is there a way to do this using upsert?  I'm trying to understand from the documentation but its a bit confusing for me.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to show what it is you are actually trying to do. Show a sample document and/or data and the expected result. It also helps to show what you have tried so far. Use the [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31767783/edit) link on your question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider [creating an unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) for `email` field to ensure that there could be only one document for any particular `email`:

```
db.collection.createIndex({email: 1}, {unique: true})
```

You could also add `sparse` option to allow documents without `email`.

Then you'll have two options depending on your particular use case: to use upsert, or to use insert ignoring duplicate key errors.

### Upsert

Using the following upsert operation

```
db.collection.update({email: email}, {$set: {name: name}}, {upsert: true})
```

you will:

1. create new document if there is no such `email` yet;
2. update existing document with new `name` if the email already exists.

Here is a quotation from [MondoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) explaining upsert behavior when no document matches the query criteria:

> The update creates a base document from the equality clauses in the **<query>** parameter, and then applies the update expressions from the **<update>** parameter.

### Insert

If you don't want to update `name` field of an existing document, you should use [basic `insert` operation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) instead:

```
db.u.insert({email: email, name: name})
```

ignoring all `11000 E11000` duplicate key errors.